# ImagePullSecrets GCR

Tags: kubernetes, service-accounts, minikube, google-container-registry

I am having an issue configuring GCR with ImagePullSecrets in my deployment.yaml file.  It cannot download the container due to permission

```
Failed to pull image "us.gcr.io/optimal-jigsaw-185903/syncope-deb": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: denied: Permission denied for "latest" from request "/v2/optimal-jigsaw-185903/syncope-deb/manifests/latest".
```

I am sure that I am doing something wrong but I followed this tutorial (and others like it) but with still no luck.

https://ryaneschinger.com/blog/using-google-container-registry-gcr-with-minikube/

The pod logs are equally useless:

```
"syncope-deb" in pod "syncope-deployment-64479cdcf5-cng57" is waiting to start: trying and failing to pull image
```

My deployment looks like:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  # Unique key of the Deployment instance
  name: syncope-deployment
  namespace: default
spec:
  # 3 Pods should exist at all times.
  replicas: 1
  # Keep record of 2 revisions for rollback
  revisionHistoryLimit: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        # Apply this label to pods and default
        # the Deployment label selector to this value
        app: syncope-deb
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: mykey
      containers:
      - name: syncope-deb
        # Run this image
        image: us.gcr.io/optimal-jigsaw-185903/syncope-deb
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9080
```

Any I have a key in my default namespace called "mykey" that looks like (Edited out the Secure Data):

```
{"https://gcr.io":{"username":"_json_key","password":"{\n  \"type\": \"service_account\",\n  \"project_id\": \"optimal-jigsaw-185903\",\n  \"private_key_id\": \"EDITED_TO_PROTECT_THE_INNOCENT\",\n  \"private_key\": \"-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\\EDITED_TO_PROTECT_THE_INNOCENT\\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\\n\",\n  \"client_email\": \"bobs-service@optimal-jigsaw-185903.iam.gserviceaccount.com\",\n  \"client_id\": \"109145305665697734423\",\n  \"auth_uri\": \"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth\",\n  \"token_uri\": \"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token\",\n  \"auth_provider_x509_cert_url\": \"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs\",\n  \"client_x509_cert_url\": \"https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/bobs-service%40optimal-jigsaw-185903.iam.gserviceaccount.com\"\n}","email":"redfalconinc@gmail.com","auth":"EDITED_TO_PROTECT_THE_INNOCENT"}}
```

I even loaded that user up with the permissions of:

- Editor Cloud Container
- Builder Cloud Container
- Builder Editor Service
- Account Actor Service
- Account Admin Storage
- Admin Storage Object
- Admin Storage Object Creator
- Storage Object Viewer

Any help would be appreciated as I am spending a lot of time on seemingly a very simple problem.

Comment: Still struggling with this issue.   I do notice that when I open the registry to in the public then it works fine.   Clearly a permissions thing but the service account that I configured has the proper level of permissions.

Is there a way to see exactly the user the minikube is trying to authenticate as?

Comment: Do you figure it out ?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is most likely caused by you using a secret of type `dockerconfigjson` and having valid `dockercfg` in it. The `kubectl` command changed at some point that causes this.

Can you check what it is marked as `dockercfg` or `dockerconfigjson` and then check if its valid `dockerconfigjson`.

The json you have provided is `dockercfg` (not the new format)

See https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/12626#issue-100691532 for info about the formats